# Using NSCoding protocol in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm having trouble implementing NSCoding in Swift. I built the following basic class to demonstrate the problem. When i run this code, i get a runtime error, such as:

"SForwarding: warning: object 0x102801f60 of class '_TtC4Projet5Test' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead"

I've seen other sample code include NSObject as a base class, but i'm using a purely Swift implementation and the documentation for NSCoding doesn't seem to mention this as a requirement.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thx.

```
class Test: NSCoding {
    var array: [String]?

    init() {

    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder!) {
        array = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("array") as? [String]
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.array, forKey: "array")
    }
}

var myTest = Test()
myTest.array = [String]()
myTest.array!.append("Nick")
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(myTest, toFile: "/Users/test/Desktop/test.archive")
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that Test does not derive from NSObject. It needs to, or there will (as the message says) trouble ahead.

```
class Test: NSObject, NSCoding {
```

The reason is that NSCoding makes various assumptions about what other messages an instance will respond to - such as `methodSignatureForSelector:`. A non-NSObject class doesn't do that. If you look at a the documentation for NSObject (and NSObjectProtocol) you'll see that there's a heck of a lot of important stuff there, all of which you give up if you don't derive from NSObject.

> the documentation for NSCoding doesn't seem to mention this as a requirement

Because NSCoding has been around for 20 years, and Swift only just came on the scene. You cannot expect the documentation to mention things like this. Stuff that comes from the Objective-C Cocoa API obviously expects Objective-C Cocoa objects.

Answer (score 2):

If a Swift class doesn't include the '@objc' directive or extend from NSObject then:

- static and vtable method dispatch will be used. This is faster but dynamic dispatch is required for many cocoa features such as KVO and message forwarding.
- Objc introspection will not work.

Pure Swift classes behave somewhat like C++, with very admirable performance but also a lot of rigidity. (But unlike C++ we have ARC, no pointers, optionals and no pointer headaches). This makes for a compelling systems programming language, and can also be used when performance tuning is required - at the times when you'd usually drop to pure C or objective c++ in a Cocoa app.

Meanwhile, Cocoa strongly depends on the dynamic and introspective nature of the ObjC runtime. And given that 95% of performance gains are made tuning 5% of your code, in a Cocoa app it is recommended to extend NSObject by default. This way all of your Cocoa features - NSCoding, KVO, etc will work as expected.